# jQuery Show/Hide Div as per the ajax response and pass the response's requestId to the success Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the below code for show/hide success div as per the service call's response plus i need to pass the Service Response's request to the Success `Div`. How do i pass the `requestId` and show the success `div`?

```html
<div id="showResponseArea" class="alert alert-success hide">
    <span>
        <strong>Success !! </strong>Your request <<requestId>> has been successfuly created !!! 
    </span>
</div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url:
    type:
    data:
    success: function(resObj){
        $("#showResponseArea span").removeClass("hide");
        var requestId = resObj.requestId;    
    }
    error: funciton(resObj){
        alert("Some Error Occured");
    }
});
```

Comment: how does  `resObj` looks like?

Comment: fyi - your error function here is a funciton instead.

Comment: please note that you are removing the hide class from the span, but who actually have it is the parent div

Comment: I would also hope you have URL, Type, and data params in your real example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are removing the `hide` class from wrong TAG `span` which does not have that class. hide class should be removed from from the parent div with id="showResponseArea" which has the hide class, secondly You need to wrap the `<<requestId>>` in span with an id. like

```
<div id="showResponseArea" class="alert hide">
<span>
    <strong>Success !! </strong>Your request <span id="requestId"> // Request id goes here</span> has been successfuly created !!! 
</span>
```

Then in the ajax success function

```
success: function(resObj){
    $("#showResponseArea").removeClass("hide");
    $("#showResponseArea").removeClass("alert-danger");
    $("#showResponseArea").addClass("alert-success");
    //OR $("#showResponseArea").removeClass("hide").show();

    var requestId = resObj.requestId;   
    $("#requestId").text(requestId ); 
},
error: function(err,xhr,status){
    $("#showResponseArea").removeClass("hide");
    $("#showResponseArea").removeClass("alert-success");
    $("#showResponseArea").addClass("alert-danger");
    //OR $("#showResponseArea").removeClass("hide").show();

    $("#requestId").text(xhr.responseText); 
}
```

Comment: error: funciton(xhr, status, error) {
            $("#requestId").text(xhr.responseText);}

Comment: $("showResponseArea).focus(); I am not able to set focus of the success div being painted by the success message.

Comment: Why you want foucs on the div ? i have edited the answer.

Comment: the reason, i want to have div focus is that my page is too long and submit button is at the bottom and my success div in the end. so user has to navigate manually to reach the success div.

Comment: $("#focus_point").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
:focus  {"outline: none !important;" }

Comment: hmm ok! Great for you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting response msg you can use it as you want in your html. You can modify response message as you want, so use .html() in your javascript code to manipulate your response msg. Your response for example can be "<strong>Success, great, foo foo foo!<strong>" or "<strong>Error, foo foo foo!<strong>". Use ajax request as function to show response, generate response message in your req page.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u14vaoou/)

HTML:

```
<div id="showResponseArea" class="alert alert-success">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url:
    type:
    data:
    success: function(msg){
        $("#showResponseArea span").html(msg); //you will paste your response msg to the span
    }
    error: funciton(msg){
        alert("Some Error Occured");
    }
});
```